# SQL | How to get all records IDs based on record id and another column ? (probably simple issue :) )

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that consists of two columns. The two columns are object_id and term_taxonomy_id. Lets say the table looks like that:

```
object_id | term_taxonomy_id
----------------------------
111       | 75
119       | 42
234       | 34
742       | 75
824       | 99
931       | 34
999       | 75
```

Now let's say that **I know** the value of the **object_id**, and I like to retrive all the object ID's that has the same term_taxonomy_id

In example, lets say that **I have the object ID 742** and I like **to get all the object_id** records that the **term_taxonomy_id is 75** so as a result I should have something like

111, 742, 999

Is it posible to achive that with a single SQL Query?

The DBMS that I am using is the MySQL.

Kind regards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Object_ID) ObjectList
FROM tableName
WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 75
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd51c/2)

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(object_id) ObjectList
FROM   tableName
WHERE  term_taxonomy_id = 
        (
          SELECT term_taxonomy_id
          FROM   tableName
          WHERE  object_id = 742
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd51c/4)

or by using `JOIN`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.object_id) ObjectList
FROM   tableName a
       INNER JOIN tableName b
       ON a.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id AND
               b.object_id = 742
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd51c/11)

Comment: The only information I have is the object_id, not the term_taxonomy_id. This was too simple :) anyway thanks for your response :)

Comment: That was too simple :) Thanks . . . I will accept your response as answer in seven minutes :) Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use below Query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.object_id FROM table as t1, table as t2
WHERE t1.object_id = XX
AND t2.term_taxonomy_id = t1.term_taxonomy_id
```